# Spring 5 Unable to find a Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Framework 5.3.7 application, NOT Spring Boot (I'll move to Spring Boot later).   I am using Java Configuration and it is working well so far.   I have a multi-maven module project, and the first module is "myapp-entity".   There is a config directory with the following file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/myapp/myapp-ws.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppEntityConfiguration
{
@Value("${hibernate.connection.driver.class}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${hibernate.connection.url}")
private String connectionUrl;

@Value("${hibernate.connection.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${hibernate.connection.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.app.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(connectionUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager()
{
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties()
{
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    return hibernateProperties;
}

}
```

The myapp-entity.jar compiles fine with Java 11, and this is fine.  The next maven module which is myapp-dao has a config directory and a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@Import(AppEntityConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.dao")
public class RepositoryContextConfiguration {
}
```

I have an TableOneEntity defined with an @Entity annotation in the app-entity.jar and that is fine.

I have a TableOneDao and TableOneDaoImpl defined with a very basic list of functions.

```
public interface TableOneDao
{     ... list of functions  }

@Repositories("tableOneDao")
public class TableOneDaoImpl implements TableOneDao
{     ... iplementation of functions  }
```

And the test for this works perfectly:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/myapp/myapp-ws.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryContextConfiguration.class)
public class OrganizationDaoTest extends BaseDaoTests
{
      @Autowired
      private TableOneDao tableOneDao;
 }
```

This is very much the old way I used to do things, and it wall worked well.  NOW, I want to get rid of this old way of doing things and go with a new way of doing things.   Maybe I can't do them in the same project, that could be the issue.

I have a second Entity (TableTwoEntity) and a second Repository (TableTwoDao):

```
@Repository("clothesDryerDao")
public interface ClothesDryerDao extends JpaRepository<ClothesDryer, Long>
{
}
```

This is now a JPA repository and when I do a simple on this Dao, it cannot find THIS Dao.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/ekotrope/ekotrope-ws.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryContextConfiguration.class)
public class ClothesDryerDaoTest extends TestCase
{
    @Autowired
    private ClothesDryerDao clothesDryerDao;
}
```

And I get the error as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ekotrope.dao.ClothesDryerDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
... 30 more
```

I thought I just need to modify the RepositoryContextConfiguration as follows:

```
 @Configuration
 @Import(EkotropeEntityConfiguration.class)
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ekotrope.dao")
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ekotrope.dao")
 public class RepositoryContextConfiguration
 {
 }
```

But this did not work.  As a matter of fact I think it broke the other working tests.  So, the question is ... can I use both these methods (Dao and DaoImpl) and (JPA Dao)?   Or, should I use only one, and if that was the case I would go with the JPA Repositories.   I just wanted to be able to demonstrate both methods to my co-workers who are not familiar with Spring.

So, if I can get both to work at the same time, that would be great, but if not, then I can create one more Maven Module and then I will have a myapp-dao-old.jar and myapp-dao-new.jar.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jpaRepositories config is wrong but yout dao is good.
And I think this 2 solutions can work together.

Firtsly you don't need to put an `@Repository` on the ClothesDryerDao interface. (I understand you want to use a qualifier but i don't think this will work will not be necessary. (Type is enough for spring injection if you don't have multiple instance of a same class)

Secondly I think you need to change your Jpa configuration.
In a project i've done something like  this

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = ClothesDryerDao.class,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "configEntityManager",
)
public class RepositoryContextConfiguration{ /
  
    //be careful this bean can maybe be in conflict with your sessionFactory
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configEntityManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        log.info("Start Parametrage Arcole Entity Manager");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.app.model");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        
        return em;
    }
}
```

Thirdly i think (this one is juste my opinion) you should maybe not mix classical Dao and Repository in the same package. For a better visibility :)
Even if the usage is the same